# Neo4j Elastic Search Integration

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j

I have data set(questions) which are mapped to multiple tags and these tags are hierarchical in  nature.
So there is A question which is mapped to t1 and t2 tag. 
t1 has parent p1 and p1 has parent p2.(p2 -> p1 - >t1 --mapped to--->A)

So i was storing my data in neo4j and I want to get A as result for p2 tag. I am getting result easily using cypher. but now i have sort and limit by in the same query and since neo4j cant use index in such queries, i am thinking of integrating neo4j with elasticsearch, but I am not able to get how to query?

```
$query = "MATCH p=(n:messages)-[r:TAGGED_TO]->(k:tags{tag_id:{tag_id}}) RETURN p,n ORDER by n.msgId desc limit 5";
$params['tag_id'] = (int)$tag_id;
$result = $this->dbHandle->run($query,$params);
```

Now sort and limit are not using index. I want to run this query in optimized way.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want ? Show some queries and desired output

Comment: edited my question, using with php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Graphaware plugin](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch) for connecting neo4j to elastic or the [apoc plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures),specifically apoc.es.* functions... see [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) for more.